# Solving Differential Equation: Adding Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+2y'+2y=e^{-3x}$$

Apparently one can solve this differential equation by first solving for the general solution of the left-hand side (= 0):

$$y''+2y'+2y= 0$$

yields

$$y = e^{-x}(c_{1}sin(x)+c_2cos(x))$$

Here's what I don't quite understand: The next step is to find an equation in the form of
$ y = se^{-3x} $ which is a solution to the original $y''+2y'+2y=e^{-3x}$.

This gives $ y = \frac{1}{5}e^{-3x}$. (s = 1/5)

Then the final correct answer is to add these two together:

$$y = e^{-x}(c_{1}sin(x)+c_2cos(x)) + \frac{1}{5}e^{-3x}$$
is the general solution to $y''+2y'+2y=e^{-3x}$.

Can someone explain how one would reach this solution? How would one know that one of the solutions is in the form of $ y = se^{-3x}$? Is it just a matter of guesswork? Why would you add these particular two solutions together?

I know that linear combinations of (different) solutions form the general solution...is that related to the solution of this problem in any way?

Comment: It looks like the RHS of your differential equation should be $e^{-3x}$ instead of $e^{3x}$.

Comment: There is some theory that you can use to find that form for the answer, but I prefer to leverage the existence and uniqueness theorems in order to sweep all of that under the rug. Once you find the answer, it no longer matters **how** you found it. As for adding solutions together, that is justified by the fact that this is a linear differential equation. These are very special indeed.

Comment: This might help: https://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-NonhomgenLinEqns_Stu.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients